# Dock glitch when closing apps

Tags: macos, dock, bug, ui

When I'm closing an app, and the dock is about to refresh the app icon (from opened to closed), and the cursor is in the area of the dock, a splitting glitch happens as show in the picture below. For less than a second. But it's quite ugly and annoying.

[image]

Is there any procedure to take that may solve such GUI-related issues on macOS Sierra?

My specs:
13" Retina MacBook Pro (late-2013) 2.4Ghz Intel Core i5, 8gb RAM, Intel Iris 1536MB, macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) It'd be useful if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/305893/edit) your question to include what model Mac you have and its specs.